# How to connect Windows Servers on different sites?

Tags: windows-server-2008, networking, vpn

I have some Windows Server 2008 R2 that are physically "off-shore". I would like to add these to my corporate network. How would you bring this server into the private LAN?

Currently I had set up VPN, but when googling for something like "Automatically connect VPN on startup" and not finding very good results I got the idea that it might not be the standard solution to use VPN.

What are the alternatives?

Answer (score 3):

Depending on what VPN technology you use, there is usually a way to have a persistent VPN connection on a server. Since you don't mention what technology you use, I can't really offer any more detail.

If you have multiple off-shore machines in the same off-shore location, you should set up a site-to-site VPN using an appropriate termination point so that there is nothing special on the servers, but all traffic funnels through the VPN.

Comment: Thanks. I am using the VPN offered through RRAS and connect with the Microsoft VPN client. Can I use this for a persistent VPN?

Answer (score 1):

More than likely you want to look into site-to-site VPN that the router/firewall/dedicted VPN decice at each of your sites would establish and maintain, instead as software running on each of the servers.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot do that because our data center is not really great ... ;)